# ANgular js show always email successfully sent although not sent

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I want to send mail to user i succeeded for that using spring boot and angular but i have a problem is that in my console always show me the message that my mail: succeesfuly sent: as mail is sent to user:

this is my angular js controller.js:

```
 $scope.sentMail = function() {  var data = new FormData();var mail= $scope.account.mail;   

 console.log('test 1 :', $scope.account.mail);
 console.log("sent mail");
 $http.post(_contextPath + '/sentEmail',mail).then(Failure)
                                             .catch(Success);   
 function Success(success) {
    // console.log(response.data);
     console.log(' email is successfully sent:', $scope.account.mail);
 }

 function Failure(error) {
     console.log('A problem occurred while sending an email.');
 }
```

}

this is my controller.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sentEmail", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ModelAndView processForgotPasswordForm(ModelAndView modelAndView, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String mail) throws MessagingException
{   
    System.out.println("print");
    User optional= usersService.findByEmail(mail);

    if((optional== null))
    {           
        modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "We didn't find an account for that e-mail address.");
    }
    else{
        optional.setResetToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        usersService.save(optional);
        String appUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName();
        SimpleMailMessage passwordResetEmail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        passwordResetEmail.setFrom("test@test.com");
        passwordResetEmail.setTo(optional.getUserEmail());
        passwordResetEmail.setSubject("Password Reset Request");
        passwordResetEmail.setText("Hello  "+  optional.getUserFirstname()+" "+ optional.getUserLastname()+", \n \n You recently request to  reset your password for rotana platform. Please click the link below to reset it : \n \n"+ appUrl +":8080/neorchaWEBPlatform"+ "/reset?token=" + optional.getResetToken()
        +"\n \n if you did not request a password reset, please ignore email or reply to let us know.\n \n Thanks, \n \n Rotana Group \n \n P.S. We also love hearing from you and helping you with any issues you have. Please reply to this email if you want to ask a question.");
        modelAndView.addObject("ResetMessage", "An  e-mail has been sent to " + optional.getUserEmail());

        emailService.sendEmail(passwordResetEmail);
    }
    modelAndView.setViewName("forgotPassword");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

any help,thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your `processForgotPasswordForm` actually return an error status and your Angular app is interpreting that as success?

Comment: @Nicholas Smith the email is sent successfully if the email exists in my database ,sure it returns error. but angular always show that successsfully sent else email not send.

Answer (score 0):

`.then` will handle 'successful' responses.  `.catch` will handle any errors in your `success` or `error` functions.  You don't have an `error` function registered.  I believe your code should be setup something like this:

```
$http.post(_contextPath + '/sentEmail',mail).then(Success, Failure)
                                             .catch(UnexpectedError);   
 function Success(success) {
    // console.log(response.data);
     console.log(' email is successfully sent:', $scope.account.mail);
 }

 function Failure(error) {
     console.log('A problem occurred while sending an email.');
 }

 function UnexpectedError(error) {
      console.log('Something unexpected happened in Success() or Failure()');
 }
```

The success and error callbacks look at the status being returned by your server.  From the Angular documentation:

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success
>   status and will result in the success callback being called. Any
>   response status code outside of that range is considered an error
>   status and will result in the error callback being called. Also,
>   status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the
>   request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout. Note that if the
>   response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it,
>   meaning that the outcome (success or error) will be determined by the
>   final response status code.

see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks for your response,i make the same as you wrote. But now if mail sent or not show me the failure message : A problem occurred while sending an email.

Comment: What http status code is your server returning to your angular app?  You should be able to monitor the network request in your browser javascript console and see the response coming back, with the status code.  I added the docs to the answer above for more explanation.

Comment: @ Nicholas Smith Thanks  for your response, i will focus in your answer and i will tell you .